# Basic Ember app not working with default adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/zachfedor/emberblog).

I'm running Ember-CLI from the master branch of the git repo (currently version 2.2.0-beta.1-master-e803ac7fa6) and linking via npm. This should be using versions 2.2.0 of Ember and Ember Data. In the middle of the basic tutorial, I hit an issue with Mirage and Ember Data. Without explicitly creating an application adapter, the app fails. There is a 404 error being thrown on the route that should be handled by Mirage, as well as numerous Adapter errors. No errors are shown during `ember serve`.

In trying to fix this, I ran into another issue. After running `ember g adapter application`, the app loaded in the browser but there was still an error because this generated a RESTAdapter instead of the preferred JSONAPIAdapter. After manually switching to the JSONAPIAdapter, everything is fine.

Is this an issue with Ember-CLI still using an old version of Ember Data somehow? **Update:** @Michael and @Gaurav found the issue with Ember-CLI. See his answer for the Github issue link.

The original question still stands, though. Should Ember be able to function without explicitly creating an adapter?

Comment: Please open an issue with ember-cli and ember-cli-mirage. Thank you.

Comment: I was already posting on an issue for the [Ember guides](https://github.com/emberjs/guides/issues/1062). I was told to create a question here. The problem doesn't seem to lie with ember-cli-mirage, so I won't post there. There are currently 233 open issues on ember-cli as they try to figure out how to convert to 2.0, so I won't add to the cacophony.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with Ember CLI 2.2.0-beta.1 - it's using the wrong adapter type by default. Can you open an issue on Ember CLI? Thanks!

Comment: Correct, there is an issue with ember-cli using the wrong adapter by default.  Thanks for finding it. But my original question refers to Ember failing without an explicitly created adapter. The secondary issue is the ember-cli bug which I ran into while trying to fix the first. The original question still stands: Should a bare Ember project be able to run fine without explicitly creating an adapter? I'll edit the question to better reflect that. My bad.